# Do something at a specific time of the day js

Tags: javascript, date, time

How can i fire a function at a specific time and date. *eg: 8:30 every Wednesday*. The solution that i can think of is checking time with an interval but loops are laggy especially when you have to check every minute. Are there any alternative solution. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Is this JS that is running in a browser? Are timezones an issue?

Comment: yes, and let's not worry about time zone just yet

Comment: You will have to check at intervals. Keep in mind that JS natively only knows the time that the users computer is set to.

Comment: Would using `setInterval()` work for you?  That would be more reliable than a loop, anyway.

Comment: What is your use case? It's pretty uncommon to need to perform a function far into the future using JS running in a browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like...

```
var dateItHappens = new Date()
// ... set the dateItHappens variable up ...
var millisTillOccurence = dateItHappens.getTime() - new Date().getTime();
setTimeout(function(){ /* ... function you want to call ... */ }, millisTillOccurence);
```

Comment: I actualy did not think of that before, that's perfect and simple, thanks!

Comment: As long as you don't use my actual code - I've fixed 4 typos already so there's probably more ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using node you can use node-cron package,
and
cron.schedule('* * * * * *',async()=>{
// your task
)

first star represent seconds, next minute and so on........

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).